# Is Magento 2 Stable enough to start developing new eshop?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I would like to **start developing** new E-Shop but my current Magento2 experience is too slow and crashy for comfortable development.

I have tried both Master and Dev branches on Windows XAMPP.
Found that both front-end shop and admin panel hangs / crashes constantly with random errors. E.g.: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1734

Is Magento 2 more stable on Unix? Is it worth trying to set it up on VM?

Comment: It is worth noting that Magento is not officially supported running in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento2 is not suitable for launching a live site on, as it's still in beta.  Although as it's something you're interested in learning, its absolutely fine for that purpose.

Yes, I would recommend learning it on Unix through a VM.  This is how most Magento devs work and it is a good place to start.

Also Magento is developed to run on linux and and there are a few things that break on WAMP, such as paths and case sensitive file names so it's easier to my mind just to get used to working on linux.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 as my linux distro, it's the most stable as they are changing it up a bit after that version.  For my VM I use oracle Virtual Box.  Vagrant is also worth looking at for setting up your dev environment, I'm going to check it out next time I'm setting up my machine.

As Marius says in his answer, once Magento2 is offically released, it will be ok to launch a live site on that release.

Have Fun :)

Comment: What about magento 2 today? is it stable enough for production

Answer (score 9):

As I'm writing this, Magento 2 is in the "merchant-beta" phase. So **Beta**.
You should not start a live shop on this version yet.
The official release is scheduled sometime in Q4 of this year.
Then you can start your live shop.

Comment: As a detail and just to dis encourage this, there are no payment methods but Check/Money order.

Comment: Sorry for misleading title. My goal is to Start development not launch a life shop. As I have 0 experience with Magento 1 I was thinking to skip it and start learning Magento 2 and develop everything on new framework.

Comment: @RawPhunky. you can already start learning it, and you might even develop on it, but be sure that some things will change until the official release. There is a chance your work might be for nothing.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, it's far too early to use it in production environments. Although beta is pretty stable as of this writing there still will be changes that might affect your current setup.

Stay put and take the latest Magento 1.9.x version instead. This branch is heavily tested and by far the safer way to go.

Comment: Sorry for misleading title. My goal is to Start development not launch a life shop. As I have 0 experience with Magento 1 I was thinking to skip it and start learning Magento 2 and develop everything on new framework.

Comment: Ok, well that's reasonable. Although Magento 2 is not all *new*, many of the core concepts still apply (EAV, layout XML, Event-Observer, etc.) and do for a good reason. If you are starting on the green I still would suggest to also have a look at Magento 1 just for the learning effect.